# Connect to SQL Server in VM using local machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dbase

I would like to connect SQl server DB in VM using my local sql server management studio.

What should I need for server name ? 
Can I use my server Windows authentication for VM in my local ?

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty text file on your VM and give it extension .udl
Doubleclick on it now you can set the properties easy from combobox
Adjust the properties and click on "test connection" until it works

Now open the file in notepad and there you see a complete connection string.

Note that for SQL Server authentication you need to configure the protocol in SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: I did this and found It's working in VM but still couldn't connect using local SSMS. However, i'm connecting throug VPN, do you think thats the issue ?

Comment: If you connect through VPN you should be on the same network. Is your sql server browser service running ? Are all protocols for tcp/ip enabled in sql server configuration manager ?

Comment: I checked the VM, it did't appear to me the browser service! the strange think its running on my college!. Do you think I have less permeation to the VM ?  what kind of issue is this ?

Comment: the sql browser must be running on the computer where sql server is installed. Not on the computer where you are connecting from. Also check in sql configuration that tcp/ip and named pipes protocols are enabled

Comment: And you should create the UDL file on the computer where you want to connect from and test from there offcourse

Answer (score 0):

Use name of the VM where SQL server is running.
And yes, you can use Windows authentication. Depending on your domain settings.

This will help you [How to: Create a SQL Server Login](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562(v=sql.105).aspx) It is not much difference from SQL login.
And if you are in Administrators group on machine running SQL Server, then your login already should be included.

And if your machine with Management Studio and server with SQL Server are in different domains, then you will need to run Management Studio under different account

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\username "c:\path\ssms.exe"
```

See [Connect to SQL Servers in another domain using Windows Authentication](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/)

Comment: How do I change my windows authentication Localy ?

Comment: When you connect using Management studio, then in connect dialog you chose `Windows Authentication` The dialog will slightly change and your windows account will be filled in.

Comment: @user2761483 But if this is your toy database server, then I would recommend start with SQL authentication. It is easier and you can easily experiment with different users.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Management studio on your local machine, you will need the hostname or IP address of the VM.

- For Windows Authentication, you will need an account on the local domain that both your workstation and the database VM are connected to.

  - For SQL server authentication, you will need an account in the SQL Server instance.

In both cases, security will need to be configured and associated with your account.

Are you on a domain, or is this just a private server?

Comment: I do have username and password for vm but i'm not able to change the windows authentication localy

Comment: Yes, this is because it is trying to pass your already-authenticated credentials from Active Directory.  You may need to make sure that the VM has the correct ports open to allow a Management Studio connection in from another machine.

Comment: Don't ask questions in your answer. Ask them in the comments then post a complete answer.