# Connect to SQL Server in VM via local SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: database, remote-server, dbase

I do have a database running in VM and I would like to connect to it using my local SQL Server Management Studio. I have my Windows authentication and I have SQL Server authentication. I don't know what the server name is supposed to be?

Could you please provide me an example, and if there's any way to get the info from the server.

Comment: This appears to be very similar to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44828682/1575353) from ~7 hours ago...

Answer (score 0):

Open up SQL Server Configuration Manager (search for it in the Start menu of your VM ). Click on SQL Server Services. The instance name of SQL Server is in parenthesis inline with SQL Server service. If it says MSSQLSERVER, then it's the default instance. To connect to it in Management Studio, just type . (dot) OR (local) and click Connect. If the instance name is different, then use .[instance name] to connect to it (for example if the instance name is SQL2008, connect to .\SQL2008).

Also make sure SQL Server and SQL Server Browser services are running, otherwise you won't be able to connect.

If SQL server and SQL Server Browswer are started, than you should connect to your VM Sql management studio.

I hope this helps :)